# Losing Access to Server After Provisioning With Chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am using the rails-server-template available here (https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/rails-server-template) to provision a Rails server (Ubuntu 12.04) using Chef. When I am setting up a new server, I copy my public ssh key `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ubuntu@my-server.amazonaws.com` and am able to enter my server fine.

But after I download a new copy of this template (updating the nodes/my-server.json file to this:)

```
{
    "environment": "production",
    "authorization": {
        "sudo": {
            "users": ["deploy", "vagrant"]
        }
    },
    "run_list": [
        "role[server]",
        "role[postgres-server]"
    ],
    "automatic": {
        "ipaddress": "my-server.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "postgresql": {
        "password": {
            "postgres": "password"
        }
    }
}
```

And also updating the deploy.json user in data_bags/users:

```
{
    "id": "deploy",
      // generate this with: openssl passwd -1 "plaintextpassword"
      "password": "password",
      "ssh_keys": [ "ssh-rsa my-public-key from ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
      ],
      "groups": [ "sysadmin"],
      "shell": "\/bin\/bash"
}
```

For some weird reason, after provisioning the server with bundle exec knife solo bootstrap ubuntu@my-server.com, I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error. When trying to log-in using ssh, I get asked for the password for the ubuntu user, which I don't know. I can't even log in with my key pair .pem file from Amazon EC2 anymore.

Am I missing something? I didn't change the server.json role, and I can't seem to figure out what is going on. Has something changed my ssh configuration during provisioning?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when I was trying to ssh into my server, the user I was using was `ubuntu`, whereas in the `data_bags`, I set up a new user with the id `deploy`. I needed to ssh in as the `deploy` user.